# Best way to send many choices through Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, api, django-rest-framework, vuejs3

I am using Django Rest Framework in conjunction with Vuejs to create a recipe costing calculator. I have a lot of unit choices (eg. grams, kilograms, liters, etc.). What is the best way to send this data through to the frontend? I've created an endpoint for it at `/ingredients/get-all-unit-choices/` that returns only an object with all the unit choices. Is this a good approach or is there a cleaner way to declare the choices and send it through to the frontend? And in general, is it a good approach to create a lot of endpoints that do and return certain things?

## unitchoices.py

```
WEIGHT_CHOICES = ["pound", "kilogram", "ounces", "grams", "tonnes"]
VOLUME_CHOICES = [
    "millileter",
    "litre",
    "gallon",
    "teaspoon",
    "tablespoon",
    "fluid-ounce",
    "quart",
    "pint",
    "cup",
]
QUANTITY_CHOICES = ["each", "dozen", "hundreds", "thousands"]
TIME_CHOICES = ["hours", "minutes", "seconds"]
LENGTH_CHOICES = ["millimeter", "meter", "centimeter", "inch", "foot", "yard"]

grouped_unit_choices = {
    "Weight": WEIGHT_CHOICES,
    "Volume": VOLUME_CHOICES,
    "Quantity": QUANTITY_CHOICES,
    "Time": TIME_CHOICES,
    "Length": LENGTH_CHOICES,
}
```

## View

This is the view that gets called by the `ingredient/get-all-unit-choices/` endpoint. I also had to create the `grouped_unit_choices` dictionary so that I can display the `<optgroup>` in the html to have some order to them

```
@api_view(["GET"])
def get_all_unit_choices(request):
    """helper view for returning all valid unit choices"""
    from .unitchoices import grouped_unit_choices

    return Response(grouped_unit_choices, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Comment: yes that's totally ok.

Comment: This is a good approach. I personally like to wait until the data is needed before loading (like on dropdown opening but add a query param to specify unit type), but unless the application is going to be very large, that could honestly be overkill.